Как можно сделать приватный проект публичным на gitlab
Как можно сделать приватный проект публичным на gitlab

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/public_access.html


Войдите в свою учетную запись GitLab.

Перейдите к проекту, который вы хотите сделать публичным.

В левом меню проекта найдите раздел "Settings" и перейдите в него.

В настройках проекта найдите раздел "Visibility, project features and permissions".

В этом разделе вы увидите параметр "Visibility level". По умолчанию он может быть установлен на "Private".

Измените значение на "Public" или "Internal", в зависимости от того, хотите ли вы сделать проект полностью открытым или доступным только для пользователей внутри вашей организации.

После изменения значения на "Public" или "Internal", нажмите кнопку "Save changes" внизу страницы, чтобы сохранить изменения.


